# Modx revolution godaddy email settings

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

I'm new to modx and I've read numerous articles regarding godaddy free email and modx smtp settings. Could someone please provide me with the proper smtp settings to get godaddy email working? I'd like to say I'm using formit.

What I've tried

username - full godaddy email address
password 
security authentication - yes
smtp host - relay-hosting.secureserver.net
smtp port - 465
use smtp - yes

I've also tried it with no authentication with port 25

I'd also like to say this site is hosted with one of godaddy's inexpensive hosting packages which comes with the free email account.

When the form is submitted, the page gets redirected to the home page, I see the email data embedded as a url parameter. However it isn't cleared, I'm not sure if there is an issue with the plugin not submitting the form correctly, or I just need to add a proper redirect. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, appeared to be a missing ` in the formit settings.